# The problem of css-loader modularization in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-loader

After the css-loader is modularized, the class names are automatically renamed. After the modularization is enabled, the pseudo-elements can no longer be used. What should I do? For example: `.title` is renamed to `.abc`, the previously defined `.title:after` cannot be used

Comment: by modularized you mean using CSS modules?

Comment: @keul Yes, use css-loader module

Comment: Beware: css-loader is a webpack loader. CSS modules is a different thing, that can be enabled by using css-loader with option `modules: true`

Answer (score 0):

After properly configured `css-loader` for enabling CSS modules you must not use React `className` with a string. So **don't use**:

```js
    <h1 className="title">
```

Instead you must import the CSS and use rules inside.

```js
import styles from "./style.css";

// ...

    <h1 className={styles.title}>
```

In this way the generated class name will always match the hashed result.

See the [CSS Modules reference](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) for more info.